# Нерекурсивный поиск в глубину

Tags: c++

Как правильно организовать данный алгоритм?

start - указываем с какой вершины начинать. В массиве visited ставим, что мы эту вершину прошли (true). Добавляем эту вершину в стек. Дальше цикл, пока стек не пустой, ищем вершины которые есть связанные с той, что в стеке, и не были еще посещены (false). Если такие находятся - отмечаем что, мы ее посетили и присваиваем шаг, на котором она была посещена (dfs) и помещаем ее в вершину стека. Потом должна выполняться проверка: если вершина, у которой все смежные были посещены, еще есть в стеке - удаляем ее.

```
void detour::DFS(int start)
{
                    int dfs = 0;
                    Stack stack;

                    visited[start] = true;
                    dfsnumber[start] = ++dfs;
                    stack.Push(start);

                    while(stack.first)
                    {
                        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
                        {
                            if((graph[stack.first->data][i]) && !(visited[i]))
                            {
                                visited[i] = true;
                                dfsnumber[i] = ++dfs;
                                stack.Push(i);
                            }
                        }

                        stack.Pop();

                    }
}
```

Граф задается матрицей смежности. dfs - шаг, на котором вершина посещена.

Comment: Опишите, что делает функция и как.

Comment: start - указываем с какой вершины начинать. В массиве visited ставим, что мы эту вершину прошли (true). Добавляем эту вершину в стэк. Дальше цикл, пока стэк не пустой, ищем вершины которые есть связаные с той, что в стэку, и не были еще посещены (false). Если такие находяться - отмечаем что, мы ее посетили и присваем шаг, на котором она была посещена (dfs) и помещаем ее в вершину стэка. Потом должна выполняться проверка: если вершина, у которой все смежные были посещены еще есть в стэке - удаляем ее.

Comment: Вы это не в комментариях пишите, а в своем вопросе. И непонятно, что ищется., и как определены структуры данных

Comment: Вопрос в том, что имеется в виду под "данным алгоритмом".  Тот алгоритм, что вы описали: это часть постановки задачи, или часть вашего решения? Надо реализовать DFS, или надо реализовать именно то, что вы описали? Надо заметить, что описанный вами алгоритм *не является алгоритмом DFS в классическом понимании*. То, что вы описали - это фактически просто BFS в котором очередь заменили на стек. Такой алгоритм эмулирует DFS-порядок обработки, но в остальном не имеет никакого отношения к DFS алгоритму. Почитайте в Вики, как выглядит классический DFS.

Answer (score 2):

Реализация *канонического* алгоритма DFS на основе явного стека предполагает хранение в каждом стека *двух* величин: вершины графа и номера связи с соседом, до которой мы выполнили просмотр.

Если предположить, что узел вашего стека содержит два целочисленных поля `data1` и `data2` (номер вершины и номер соседа соответственно) и, соответственно, функция `Push` принимает два параметра, то реализация канонического DFS в терминах и стилистике ваших структур данных может выглядеть примерно так

```
void detour::DFS(int start)
{
  int dfs = 0;
  Stack stack;

  visited[start] = true;
  dfsnumber[start] = ++dfs;

  stack.Push(start, 0); // (Вершина, Начальный сосед)

  while (stack.first)
  {
    int v = stack.first->data1;
    // Текущая вершина

    int i = stack.first->data2; 
    // Продолжаем просмотр соседей с соседа `i`

    for (; i < size; ++i)
      if (graph[v][i] && !visited[i])
      { // Найдена новая вершина
        visited[i] = true;
        dfsnumber[i] = ++dfs;

        stack.first->data2 = i + 1; 
        // Запомним, что когда мы вернемся в эту вершину, то продолжать 
        // просмотр надо будет с соседа `i + 1`

        stack.Push(i, 0);
        // Новая вершина: (Вершина, Начальный сосед)

        // Прерываем обработку текущей вершины и немедленно переходим к
        // обработке новой вершины
        break;
      }

    if (i == size)
      // Все соседи текущей вершины просмотрены и ничего нового больше не
      // найдено - прощаемся с вершиной и делаем шаг назад
      stack.Pop();
  }
}
```

То же, что попытались реализовать вы - это просто BFS, в котором очередь FIFO подменили на стек LIFO. Вопреки распространенному верованию (неизвестного происхождения), такой алгоритм не является алгоритмом DFS, по крайней мере в классическом его понимании.

Одним из критериев канонической реализации DFS является то, что при обходе звездчатого графа в алгоритме DFS глубина стека равна O(1) и фактически никогда не вырастает больше 1 или 2 (в зависимости от реализации). В вашем же алгоритме глубина стека составит O(N), а именно: на первом же шаге алгоритма она взрывным образом вырастет до `N`.

Хоть ваш алгоритм и в состоянии воспроизвести DFS-порядок обработки вершин на *прямом ходе* DFS, он не является DFS. Также ваш алгоритм не в состоянии естественно поддержать концепцию *обратного хода* DFS - еще один ключевой признак настоящего DFS алгоритма.

Answer (score 0):

У вас глобальная ошибка в логике.

```
while(stack.first){
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
       /*...*/ 
       stack.Push(i);
   }

   stack.Pop();
}
```

Вы кладёте в стек сразу все смежные с данной вершиной. Так делать нельзя. Если вам сильно нужно написать нерекурсивный вариант рекурсивного алгоритма, то нужно хранить переменные `i` (для каждого значения стека) в массиве.

Пример теста:

```
1->2
2->3
2->4
3->4
```

Ожидание - `1->2->3->4` ваш вывод (если докодить) `1->2->4->3`.

> если вершина, у которой все смежные были посещены, еще есть в стеке -
>   удаляем ее

Тут странная формулировка, наверное имелось ввиду в вершине стека.
Если это исправить то код скорее всего будет рабочий.