# Проблема с поиском в глубину

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

написал рекурсивную реализацию поиска в глубину, которая отлично работает:

```
void DFSRecursive(int vertex, const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& graph, std::vector<bool>& visitedVertices)
{
    visitedVertices.at(vertex) = true;
    for (std::uint8_t i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++)
        if ((graph.at(vertex).at(i) != 0) && (!visitedVertices.at(i)))
            DFSRecursive(i, graph, visitedVertices);
}
```

После чего решил написать не рекурсивную реализацию, и столкнулся с проблемой зацикливания в разных участках... Да и к тому же алгоритм получился очень медленным из-за постоянного поиска в векторе. Может кто-нибудь подскажет более элегантное решение и в чем была проблема? Вот сам код:

```
void DFSNonRecursive(int startVertex, const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& graph)
{
    std::vector<int> visitedVertices;
    visitedVertices.push_back(startVertex);
    while (!visitedVertices.empty())
    {
        const int vertex = visitedVertices.back();
        bool hasAdjacentVertices = false;
        for (std::uint8_t i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++)
        {
            auto iterator = std::find(visitedVertices.begin(), visitedVertices.end(), i);
            if ((graph.at(vertex).at(i) != 0) && (iterator == visitedVertices.end()))
            {
                visitedVertices.push_back(i);
                hasAdjacentVertices = true;
            }
        }

        if (!hasAdjacentVertices)
            visitedVertices.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему бы не обойтись обычным стеком?... к чему эти мучения с вектором?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586601/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83

Comment: А как при помощи стэка отследить повторный вход в одну и туже вершину?

Comment: Как и везде - с помощью флага, например. У Кормена этот флаг цветной, например - белый, серый, черный.

Comment: @Harry, не могли бы вы привести подробный пример про флаги и как их использовать?