# Как сделать поиск в глубину максимально быстро во внешней памяти?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Интересует алгоритм или/и пример кода на C++.

*Дополнительная информация из комментариев:*

Граф задан списками смежности: один файл с вершинами + указателями на место в другом файле, где находятся смежные этой вершине вершины. Но можно преобразовать это в другой формат, конечно, если будет быстрее.

Размер графа на порядок больше размера оперативной памяти. Вершины для простоты -- натуральные числа. Можно использовать сколько угодно потоков, но не понимаю, как это поможет. Задача не в использовании чего-то готового, а в придумывании алгоритма/кода по алгоритму.

Надо придумать алгоритм, который минимизирует количество чтений из внешней памяти во внутреннюю, потому что это узкое место.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115216/discussion-on-question-by-bezos--------).

Answer (score 0):

Поиск в глубину можно реализовать ака рекурсивно, так и итеративно. В данном случае первый вариант алгоритмам может не подойти из-за глубокого дерева рекурсии, которое получается в ходе выполнения алгоритма и может вызвать ошибку переполнения памяти.

А во втором варианте используется стек. С примером кода на С++ можно познакомиться здесь: [Нерекурсивный поиск в глубину](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586601/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

Comment: А где тут внешняя память?